# ¿Como puedo agregar un segundo navigation drawer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Como puedo agregar un segundo `navigation drawer`

Convertir la parte de `onCreateOptionsMenu` a un `navigation drawer`

```
    public class Inicio extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_inicio);


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Zona Segura", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.inicio, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;



    }
}
```

modificar esta parte

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.inicio, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Quieres segundo navigation para tener mas opciones de menu para cada fragment ?

Comment: quiero agregar un segundo navigation pero en el lado derecho @Ashley G.

Comment: Tengo entendido que tecnicamente no se puede, pero puedas usar tabs dentro de los fragment o hacer submenus en tu navigation

Comment: ¿Dos Navigation Drawer? Eso no es compatible con las reglas de [Material Design](https://material.io/guidelines/). Hazte un tour por esa página y contrasta  tus conceptos de diseño con lo que es propuesto allí ([el enlace específico para Navigation Drawer es este](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-behavior)). Una App con un Navigation Drawer de cada lado es, con todo respeto, una barbaridad. Tu App debe parecerse a las Apps que ya existen... ¿tú has visto alguna con un ND de cada lado?

Comment: He encontrado ese tutorial, bueno mi respuesta parte de el https://updateunlimited.blogspot.com.es/2015/12/double-sided-nav-drawers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución siguiendo parte de ese [tutorial](https://updateunlimited.blogspot.com.es/2015/12/double-sided-nav-drawers.html) he simplificado las escuchas de las accione y algo más...

Partiendo de añadir una actividad con menú lateral que genera el Android Studio 3.0

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Añadiendo los NavigationView

Añadir el segundo `NavigationView` debajo del primero en `activity_main.xml`

- renombrar el primero por `nav_view_right` y el segundo `nav_view_right`
- Los atributos `app:headerLayout` para cargar otra vista dentro de el o bien `app:menu` asignar un menú
- El segundo `NavigationView` definir que se abre des de la derecha `android:layout_gravity="end"`

  ```
  <include
      layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/nav_view_left"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="end"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
      app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
      android:id="@+id/nav_view_right"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="start"
      android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
      app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
      app:menu="@menu/activity_secondary_drawer" />
  ```

#### Crear los menús de los navigations

Crea el menú del la derecha `menu/activity_secondary_drawer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view">

    <item android:title="Communicate">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_info"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_share"
                android:title="Share" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_about"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
                android:title="Send" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

#### Asignar el segundo navigation

En el `MainActivity.java` cargar el segundo navigation y asignar el gestor de acciones

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

NavigationView leftNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view_left);
leftNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

NavigationView rightNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view_right);
rightNavigationView .setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

#### Computando las acciones de los menus

En el evento `onNavigationItemSelected` donde se detecta las acciones de ambos menús laterales

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {
        //Left Panel
        case R.id.nav_camera:

            break;
        case R.id.nav_gallery:

            break;
        case R.id.nav_slideshow:

            break;
        case R.id.nav_manage:

            break;
        case R.id.nav_share:

            break;
        case R.id.nav_send:

            break;
        //Right Panel
        case R.id.nav_info:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right info action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_about:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right info about", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    return true;
}
```

#### Interceptar botón atras

Interceptar la acción de botón atrás y cerrar ambos menús

- Para referirse menú izquierda `GravityCompat.START`
- Para referirse menú derecha `GravityCompat.END`

Modifica:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

#### Resultado

Más o menos tendrás lo siguiente, al pulsar el icono del menu se abrirá el menú de izquierda, para hacer aparecer el menú de la derecha se debe hacer deslizando el dedo des de el borde de la derecha.

- Si quieres que se abre con un botón `drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]